# Writes id instead of name

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am new to Django, I have such a problem that Id is written instead of the category name, how can this be solved? Attached code, code not complete (only used part). I don't know how to do it anymore, most likely the problem is in views.py

**model.py**

```
    class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Post(models.Model):
    PostAuthor = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    PostNews = 'PN'
    PostArticle = 'PA'

    # «статья» или «новость»
    POSITIONS = [
        (PostArticle, 'Статья'),
        (PostNews, 'Новость'),
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    positions = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=POSITIONS, default=PostArticle)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    postCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='PostCategory')
    previewName = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField()
    rating = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def like(self):
        self.rating +=1
        self.save()

    def dislike(self):
        self.rating -=1
        self.save()

    def preview(self):
        return self.text[0:124] + '...'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/news/{self.pk}'

class PostCategory(models.Model):
    pcPost = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pcCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пост категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.pcPost)}, имеет категорию {str(self.pcCategory)}'
```

**views.py** I think the mistake is here

```
class new(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
model = Post
template_name = 'new_home.html'
context_object_name = 'new'
permission_required = 'news.view_post'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['com_post'] = Comment.objects.filter(commentPost=self.kwargs['pk']).values("commentText")
    context['pc_post'] = PostCategory.objects.filter(pcPost=self.kwargs['pk']).values('pcCategory')
    return context
```

**new_home.html**  Garbage code, but I'm just learning

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>{%extends 'flatpages/default.html'%} {% load custom_filters %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{%block title%} {{new.title|censor_filter}} {%endblock title%}</title>
</head>
<body>
{%block content%}
<h2>{{new.title|censor_filter}}</h2>
<hr>
<h4>Пост опубликован: {{new.data}}</h4>
<hr>
<h5>{{new.text|censor_filter}}</h5>
<hr>
<h6>Пост опубликовал: {{new.PostAuthor}}</h6>
<hr>
{%for pc in pc_post%}
<button><span style="color: #000000;"><a style="color: #000000;" href="{%url 'category_detail' pc.pcCategory %}">Категория: {{pc.pcCategory}}</a></span></button>
{%endfor%}

{%for comment in com_post%}
<p>Комментарии: {{comment.commentText}}</p>
{%endfor%}

{%endblock content%}
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py in apps "news"**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

path('category/<int:pk>/', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
path('category/<int:pk>/subscribe/', subscribe, name='subscribe'),
path('category/<int:pk>/unsubscribe/', unsubscribe, name='unsubscribe'),
path('category/sub/confirm/', SubsConfirm.as_view(), name='sub_confirm'),
path('category/sub/unconfirm/', SubsUnConfirm.as_view(), name='sub_unconfirm'),
path('categories/', CatigoriesView.as_view(), name = 'categories_list'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you are writing queries using `values` which will return a *dictionary* with the values being the actual values stored in the database. Hence since `pcCategory` is a `ForeignKey` the value stored in the database is the `id` of the related instance and hence that is what is displayed in your template. Simply remove the call to `values` and it should work as expected:

```
context['pc_post'] = PostCategory.objects.filter(pcPost=self.kwargs['pk']) # No call to `values`
```

Also in your template you have the below line which will now cause an error:

```
href="{%url 'category_detail' pc.pcCategory %}"
```

Change this to:

```
href="{%url 'category_detail' pc.pcCategory.pk %}"
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /news/32
Reverse for 'category_detail' with arguments '(<Category: IT>,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['news/category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: @BlackBlack change `{%url 'category_detail' pc.pcCategory %}` to `{%url 'category_detail' pc.pcCategory.pk %}`

Answer (score 0):

In your template, use the dot notation to get to the attribute you want following down the foreign key relationships.

So instead of `{{pc.pcCategory}}` use `{{pc.pcCategory.category_name}}`

Comment: Outputs nothing, just emptiness

Comment: yes, sorry, didn't notice the `.values` tacked on to the end of your queries.